# Búsqueda que no empiece con una letra en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de realizar una query en la cual quiero buscar todos los que no empiecen con una letra del abecedario, pero no he encontrado algo que me sirva ya que solo me aparece el like.

```
select *
  from datos
 where name not like '%a';
```

Debo realizar la búsqueda por los que coincidan que no empiecen con cualquier letra, no solo con a, pero no quiero poner de la A la Z.

Answer (score 1):

Esta solución es específica para MySQL, según [la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html). Para este tipo de búsqueda se usan expresiones regulares, que en MySQL se aplican con los operadores `REGEXP` y `RLIKE`. La expresión regular `^[A-Za-z]` acepta cadenas que comienzan por una letra, por lo tanto también habría que negarla.

```sql
select *
  from datos
 where name not regexp '^[A-Za-z]';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tabla
where name not regexp '^[A-Za-z]'
```

Esta consulta usa una **expresión regular** donde se seleccionarán los registros cuyo nombre no empiecen en el rango de la **'a' a la 'z'** ni de la **'A' a la 'Z'** para ello se usa la **expresión regular**:

```
'^[A-Za-z]'
```

Donde **regexp** es el **operador de expresión regular** y el caracter **"^"** representa el inicio de la cadena y los caracteres **[]** permiten agrupar caracteres en grupos o clases.

Comment: El operador `like` no admite clases de caracteres, solo los wildcards `%` y `_`.

Comment: @don_aman arreglado, gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
 select DISTINCT(city) from station where city not like 'A%' AND city not like 'E%' AND city not like 'I%' AND city not like 'O%' AND city not like 'U%';
```

Con el not like evitamos todas las ciudades que comienzan con vocales y con la funcion DISTINCT eliminamos los repetidos.

Espero te funcione Saludos!

Comment: Ojo que dice _una letra del abecedario_, no solo una vocal. Por eso es que además dice _pero no quiero poner de la A la Z_.

Answer (score 0):

Toma la primer position sola y examina esta:

```
select *
  from datos
 where upper(left(name, 1))) not between 'A' and 'Z';
```